# Accessibility on replaced radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, wai-aria

On our site we are using JavaScript to replace radio buttons and check boxes with replacements so it becomes easier to style or use image replacements. It seems to mostly work out quite well, but we had a complaint from a blind user when he was trying to fill out a form in a table.

We were already using the proper mark up for the table, but the issue seems to come from using link elements as replacement. I have updated it to the aria roles and states and tried testing it with JAWS, but I am not sure if the result I am getting is in any way better than the original.

I have mocked up a simplified version here http://jsfiddle.net/vfquA/2/

The main bit I have updated is adding the aria labelledby attribute. In addition to that I added the role to the link and update the aria-checked state, but with my testing with JAWS I am not sure if it was an improvement or something a blind person wouldn't expect.

```
<a data-for="spring1" href="#nogo" aria-role="radio" aria-checked="false" class="skin" aria-labelledby="spring1_label">&nbsp;</a>
```

It would be good if somebody had a suggestion on how to improve the accessibility without changing the replacement method completely since that would involve a lot of re-testing/ fixing across the whole system.

Comment: What was the blind user's complain exactly?

Comment: The complaint was that it was impossible to complete and that the answers are all unmarked .php links. So I assume it was reading out the link in the href instead of the label for the input.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're having to use an `<a>` rather than a different element? After all you're able use Custom styles on form tags. It's just to me that using an anchor tag for a form control is indeed very deceiving.

Comment: I am not sure why it was done like that originally, maybe so we would have an interactive element that you can tab through, but it should be fine to change. I have updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP2h/1/ to switch it to spans with a tabindex, but when I now try to select something with space it caught by JAWS (I think) and it jumps to the desktop instead of selecting it. It works fine via keyboard when JAWS isn't enabled

Comment: I do believe it's due to the extra work involved with constructing Pure CSS Custom Radio Inputs, it's doable - but for Accessibility sake - you're going to always be better off using standard DOM Elements for forms, I think it's little cosmetic pay-off for using your own tick boxes & radio buttons. My IT dissertation had some JAWS involvement and from experience you're far better off sticking by W3C's recommendations, rather than absolutely positioning the form elements away far from the screen and tricking the end user.

Comment: The click handler on a proper form label is already setup to toggle proper checkbox and radio button. Labels can be styled to look like whatever you want add some pseudo elements, and a span if you really need it, and you can use CSS to hide the actual form elements.

Tables are also absolutely horrible for accessibility. If at all possible, it's always better to use semantic markup and reserve tables for strictly tabular data.